# Eclipse - Comment multiple files at once?

Tags: eclipse, shortcut, rad, comments

Is there any way to comment multiple files at once in Eclipse?
If I've a package with 100+ class and if I want to comment all those 100+ classes, how do I do it in an efficient way? Rather than opening each class and do ctrl+a & ctrl+shift+/ .

Comment: Why do you want to comment 100+ classes in the first place?

Comment: For testing purpose.

Comment: Why not delete them? And later restore.

Comment: Thanks but commenting every class is the only option I've.

Comment: Is there something special about the comments you want to add that you're not just writing an application to do it?

Comment: Do you want to comment the content of the whole class files?Or just only few methods in a class file or few lines in a given method. Question says nothing about how do you want to comment.Is there any rule to it?

Comment: I want the whole class to be commented.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is for debugging purpose?

Just create a copy of your system in a new folder, move everything out except the class you want to work with. When you're finished with the first one, move in a new class and debug away (if that's what you're doing!).

Comment: Yes but commenting every class is the only option I've.